# supervisor field on the page of the title with Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I am editing a presentation of a research project, I am wondering if there is a field for "supervisor" on the page of the title, for instance `\supervisor`(which actually does not work)... If not, where do people conventionally add it?

Answer (score 11):

As already mentioned by Marco Daniel, a field `\supervisor` does not exist in `beamer`. However, I would like to follow a different approach.

mregine on [latex-community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9012) mentioned that you can just include the supervisors in the `\author` command which also lets you associate the affiliations to the supervisors. To make only your name appear in the footline, use the optional argument of the `\author` command. Thus, I would suggest a command like the following:

```
\author[author1]{author1\inst{1}\\[1ex]  {\small supervisor1\inst{1,2}}
```

I hope this is close to what you want.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
\author[author1]{author1\\[10mm]{\small Supervisors: supervisor1 \\ \hspace{18mm} supervisor2}}
```

After substituting the names, you have to find the XXmm yourself by trial and error.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Quite similar to the other answer ;)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it is a lot alike. I think there is a missing curly bracket at the end of the previous answer by @tc88

Answer (score 9):

A field like `\supervisor` doesn't exist in `beamer`. If you want to insert additional field to the titlepage you can create your own titlepage.

In other way is to use the optional argument of `\author` and co.

```
\author[<used as label>]{<used on titelpage>}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this might work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\title{Thermal Hydraulics}

\author{{John Williams} & {Johanna Williams} \\
{\and} \\
{\textit{Supervisors}} \\
{Jack Williams} \\ {Jackie Smith}}

\institute{LaTeX University}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I compiled the code on Overleaf and it gave this:
[image]

You may also put the authors on separate lines, replacing the `\author` command with:

```
\author{{John Williams} \\ {Johanna Williams} \\
{\and} \\
{\textit{Supervisors}} \\
{Jack Williams} \\ {Jackie Smith}}
```

which will give you:
[image]